# Submodules not working in GitExtensions

Tags: git-extensions

I'm still new to git so i might be doing something wrong but it seems like after adding a submodule using GitExtensions the Init, Update and Sync options do nothing at all. this is what i did

1. Set up a Repository for the Main Project and did the inital commit
2. Set up a Repository in a different location for the Shared Components
3. Using GitExtensions Add a Submodule for the Shared components. This creates a .gitmodules in my main projects repository, folder under my Main project and a .git file with the name a chose as Local
4. Select Init - Nothing changes, the submodule is not cloned into the newly created location
5. Select Update - Same thing nothing happened
6. Select Sync - Same thing nothing happened.

What am i missing?

Comment: Have a look at last release (2.32) it has some bug fixes on submodules